# Save Metadata about columns of a table when creating It in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, metadata

I am creating a tool that creates POCO classes from database

I want the tool to add data annotations to created class properties in Persian languague that I could use in `ErrorMessages` or my `Views` and ...

I want to know if there is any way to save metadata about table columns in `sys Tables or etc` when creating a table in sql server using `TSQL` so when I create a table I would be able to save It's Persian name in some sort of metadata that I can retrieve further using ways like `information_schema`

To be more clear , suppose I have the following script that creates a table :

```
create table dbo.Personnel
(
    ID      uniqueidentifier not null,
    Name    nvarchar(50)     not null
)
```

what I want is to store metadata about table names and column names that would be their name in Persian language !

for instance the Table name in Persian is :  'کارکنان'

and the columns names are :    'شناسه' and 'نام'

One simple way would be that I create a table of my own that stores all tables and column names and their Persian equivalents and insert metadata into that table after creating each table and in my tool I can join them with `information_schema` !

BUT

before doing such customization I would like to know if the sqlserver itself supports any way to store such metadata by it's own sys tables or anything else that I am not aware of !

thanks in advance

Comment: It isn't totally clear what you are trying to do but I think you should take a look at "extended properties". You can add whatever properties you need and and add values to those properties.

Comment: @SeanLange I edited my question and added more explanation to It .

Comment: As Sean said, look [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for information about _extended properties_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can for the table, and columns.

```
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'PersianName', @value=N' ''کارکنان'' ' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'Personnel'


EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'PersianColumnName', @value=N' ''شناسه''' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'Personnel', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'Name'
```

Comment: thanks , and any suggestion how to retrieve extendedproperty and its values using tsql ?

Comment: @Karamafrooz Read https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186989%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: @Karamafrooz No problem. is it worth it for an accepted answer? ;)